# tests are not run during maven test procedure from IDE (using surefire)

Tags: maven, maven-surefire-plugin

In my `Spring` app I have tests named properly:

```
src
 -main
 -test
    -java
       -com.mypackage.sth
           -utils
              SomethingTest.java
```

I can run it straight from the IDE `intellij`, but when I chose it from maven window:

[image]

I'm getting info:

```
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]  T E S T S
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] Results:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
```

in my `pom.xml` file I have this section:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.22.1</version>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
                    <version>5.4.0</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

I also have a dependency added above:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
        <version>5.4.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

The test still don't run though. How can I fix it? What's the main problem here?

----- EDIT
I did exactly what Naor Tedgi suggested in the first answer, however right after adding:

```
<sourceDirectory>src/main/..</sourceDirectory>
<testSourceDirectory>src/test/..</testSourceDirectory>
```

to the `<build>` tag, my project structure went nuts, after doing so it looks like this:

```
src
 -main
 -test.java.com.mypackage.sth
      -utils
           SomethingTest.java
```

and all the symbols in test classes are not resolvable. Now when I try to run tests, they run! so that's a good thing, but there are lots and lots of errors, e.g.

```
package org.junit does not exist
```

etc.

--- EDIT v2
okay, I edited my pom.xml so that now it contains these two lines in `<build>`:

```
<sourceDirectory>src/main/java/</sourceDirectory>
<testSourceDirectory>src/test/java/</testSourceDirectory>
```

errors disappeared and the project is compilable, however it still didn't help - the tests did not run

Here's the output from `mvn test`:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building myProject 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.1.0:resources (default-resources) @ projectName ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.0:compile (default-compile) @ projectName ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.1.0:testResources (default-testResources) @ projectName ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\path\to\myProject\src\test\resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.0:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ projectName ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.1:test (default-test) @ projectName ---
[INFO]
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]  T E S T S
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] Results:
[INFO]
[INFO] Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 10.181 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-02-27T17:16:29+01:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 22M/224M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: add test file example please and also validate by clicking  ctrl+shift+f10 to see if you can run the test manually

Comment: I can run them manually, when I'm in a test file and hit ctrl+shift+f10 then the current highlighted test is run. My tests are rather simple, `@Test public void should...Test() { //when something //then assertEquals(x, y); }` etc. I think there's no problem with the test class itself, but rather somewhere with surefire configuration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first, extract Junit outside of build tag into **dependencies**

then add this lines to build

```
   <sourceDirectory>src/main/{PATH TO SRC}</sourceDirectory>
   <testSourceDirectory>src/test/{PATH TO TESTS}</testSourceDirectory>
```

should look something like this

```
<project>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>

   <sourceDirectory>src/main/{PATH TO SRC}</sourceDirectory>
   <testSourceDirectory>src/test/{PATH TO TESTS}</testSourceDirectory>

        <plugins>
            <!-- JUnit 5 requires Surefire version 2.22.0 or higher -->
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.0</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

Comment: run `mvn test`  and attech output please

Comment: I've attached it to the original question

Comment: my mistake it wasn't clear from my answer you need to set the test and sources folder and fill the path instead of `..`

Comment: Naor, well I did fill it, I have those values there: `<sourceDirectory>src/main/java/</sourceDirectory><testSourceDirectory>src/test/java/</testSourceDirectory>`, however it still doesn't work... is there anything else that come up to your mind?

Comment: how did you create your project? which maven archetype did you choose?

Comment: This is my project from pom: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
 <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>` is that what you're asking for? :)

Comment: Naor, I just changed the surefire version to `2.21.0` and it works.... :|

Comment: so besides changing versions I also performed changes suggested by you, therefore I'm marking this answer as the one that helped me, thanks man!